# Is it possible to determine the Form name in ASP.NET MVC 3? Or at least get the auto-generated name?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to determine the Form name in ASP.NET MVC 3? Or at least get the auto-generated name?

I think it should be an option of `Html.BeginForm` and `Ajax.BeginForm` but it isn't. I already googled it but didn't find anything.

I need it because I'd like to submit the form using jQuery. By the way... Is there a helper method for generating form submition code in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC does not autogenerate a form name. But you can pass an explicit one in:

```
Html.BeginForm(actionName: null, controlleName: null, method: FormMethod.Post,
               htmlAttributes: new { name = "YourName" })
```

Comment: I think our two answers complete each other. <3   :)

Answer (score 1):

[BeginForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505151.aspx) takes a `IDictionary<string, Object>` type `htmlAttributes` parameter where you can specify the form name.